# pcre \Q and \E match error

Tags: pcre

```
string sContent="the path is e:\\develop\\East\\parser(delay)";
string path="e:\\develop\\East\\parser(delay)";

char sRegex[128]; sprintf(sRegex, "\\Q%s\\E", src_str);

pcrecpp::RE(sRegex).PartialMatch(sContent);
```

It doesn't match, cause `"\\East" will abort '\Q'`。How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the problem with the `\Q`..`\E` feature.

Instead of using it, you can use `string quoted = RE::QuoteMeta(src_str);` that will escape all special regex characters in a string including backslashes.

[source](http://man.he.net/man3/pcrecpp): QUOTING METACHARACTERS